# IP Tables - Blocking OpenVPN tun0 from accessing ports 80 & 443 on internal network

Tags: server, iptables, openvpn, firewall

Im looking for some help with IP tables.

I want to set a rule that incoming OpenVPN connections cannot use ports 443 and 80 in the internal network. Just to clarify I wish for them to still be able to use these ports to get out to the internet but don't want them to be able to access anything on our subnet with these ports. I should also clarify that the only other ports the incoming OpenVPN users are allowed to use are 53 (DNS) & 3389 (RDP)

I want them to be able to use 
443
80
53
3389

But for ports 443 & 80 I want them to not be able to use these ports for our internal subnet.

This is what I have tried so far :

```
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -p udp -m udp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p udp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p udp --dport 443 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p udp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p udp --dport 443 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i tun0 -p udp --dport 443 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p udp --dport 80 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p udp --dport 443 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p udp --dport 80 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p udp --dport 443 -j DROP
#-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```